# How to detect cursor change by any application in X11 using python?

Tags: python, qt, gtk, mouse, x11

I'd like my application to track when other X11 applications change the mouse cursor, e.g. when it changes from an arrow to the text cursor when you mouse over text. What's the simplest way to do this from Python?

I've figured out that the Xcursor library lets you read the current cursor in C, but:

1. Will this work for both Gtk/Qt?
2. I'm curious if doing this in python will mean writing bindings?
3. Is a more efficient way to listen for the event than just checking on a timer?

Comment: See the `CursorNotify` event: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/fixesproto/plain/fixesproto.txt

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect to find direct support in the protocol :D

Comment: Hello, I am looking for something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752051/periodically-detect-change-of-mouse-pointer-type Could you please post short code example how to print cursor change for example from hand to arrow?