# periodically detect change of mouse pointer type

Tags: python

please how can I detect change of mouse pointer type? I would like to print every
mouse pointer change (arrow, hand, ...) while moving my mouse over screen.
How can I do this? (for now I need it for windows, but cross-platform
solution is highly appreciated) What module shoudl I use? 
(I tried autopy, pygame but it seems these are not able to do this)

Many thanks.

Comment: Possibly there's no solution, that works on all OS. Maybe have a look at https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/ or https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput for a cross-platform library. Or maybe specify in your question for which OS your searching the solution. Windows? Linux?

Comment: thanks guys, preferably windows, but it could be win, linux, mac as well.