# Python How do I know when my mouse cursor is selecting a link

Tags: python-3.7

So I am trying to detect when my mouse cursor is selecting a link or becoming like this. --->
[image]

I looked around and found nothing related to this.
Is there a Python method to do this?  If no any other solutions?

Comment: Is this cursor hovering on your own python program, or are you looking to detect the mouse cursor globally?

Comment: Doing it globally.

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752051/periodically-detect-change-of-mouse-pointer-type but that question is also abandoned and the mentioned libraries in the comment all point to dead libraries. Can you clarify what's exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to catch when my mouse cursor is hovering over a link in a browser.  So I can then run functions with it.

Comment: Would be much easier to use Selenium, [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position) cursor position then [identify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910534/executing-javascript-elementfrompoint-through-selenium-driver) the element under the cursor, that way you can interact and parse the actual HTML element.

Comment: I don't know anything about Javascript or C#, so thats not easy for me.

Comment: Ah Selenium is language-agnostic, you can use it from Python. But unless you're up to resurrecting the libraries mentioned in the dupe question, you'll have to use Javascript.